# Chrome adds scrollbar on responsive view (not on window shrinking, only on responsive mode)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I have strange situation, in mobile devices' preview (the responsive mode in inspector), the website gets a horizontal scrollbar. It is not about too small window size, because even if I set the mobile window width to 20000px, it gets broken, it looks like `body{overflow-x:hidden}` stops to work. It doesn't happen when I shrink the browser's window, even on 400px browser's width is ok.

I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, and in Firefox there's no problem, but in Firefox on Android it already is the same broken.

The things that streach the window are few ::after and ::before pseudoelements that should be always 100% of the window, but in this case of reponsive view, they stretch the website instead of shrinking to the window size.

So the example you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/d5L4npv9/1/
But copy it into empty .html file and display it normally in browser's window, because the issue is somewhere in  and JSfiddle doesn't reproduce it.

This is the only hint I havae, the pseudoelements, but why they are ok on normal mode? I thought that devices emulator is only for devices screen size, but clearly it changes something more.

Comment: try and reproduce it on stackblitz.io

Comment: Please put up enough code in a SO snippet that we can run to see the problem for ourselves. It's very difficult to debug something when there is no code. You are encouraged to make a minimal reproducible example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've put the example, it turns out that it is somewhere in <body>, that looses overflow-x:hidden on responsive mode.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the magic happens when I add "minimum-scale=1.0" to the viewport. Then the website doesn't change after switching to responsive view. But I don't know why, none of my viewports have the minimum-scale, and the problem never happened before.